# accessing items from dropdown menu without having id

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to access a link (called Templates) from a dropdown (called MAIL), but that does not contain the id of that element. also the find_element_by_classname doesnt seem to work

here's the code that im working on.

```
<a href style=color .... ; uib-dropdown-toggle class ="dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='true'>
<img sec = ....>
<br>
"Mail"
</a>
<u1 class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu="menu" aria-labelledby ="...">
  <li role = "menuitems">
    <a href="/mail-template"> Templates</a>
  </li>
</u1>

(PS - '...' - sometext)
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to [Locating Hyperlinks by Link Text](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-hyperlinks-by-link-text) you may simply find the element by text (or partial text)

Try:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox

browser.get("http://yoururl.domain/") # load the page

e = browser.find_element_by_link_text("Templates")
e.click()
```

Comment: Hi, tried this in the first place, just like i accessed other links but still im failing ,  there are methods to access dropdowns but those are not working as well.

Answer (score 0):

`

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox
browser.get("http://yoururl.domain/") # load the page
e = browser.find_element_by_cssSelector("a[href='/mail-template']")
e.click()`
```

Comment: i failed to load, this is the message i got   "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a[href='/mail-template']"}"

Comment: try without the '/'